# Updating vendor details for item

Tags: acumatica

We are trying to update vendor item detail records for an item.  The default vendor already exists since it was imported at the time of the item import.  However, when we try to update the vendor's item number on the record, we get the following error:

Error: An error occurred during processing of the field Purchase Unit value EA.  An attempt was made to add a duplicate entry.

Comment: Are you trying to update via an Import Scenario?

Comment: Yes, Import Scenario

Answer (score 0):

The error you see is when you try to add a new line to the vendor list on the stock item screen with the same information (vendorID, UOM) as an existing line. Looks like the import scenario defaults to a new line, if you change the mapping for Line Number from ='-1' to a field from your provider and populate the field with 0 it updates the first vendor in the list. I don't see lineNbr in the DAC, but in testing it starts at 0 and increments by 1. [image: Import Scenario Mapping]
[image: Import Scenario Processed]
[image: Stock Item Updated]